# How is Entity Framework creating its proxies?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I understand the usage of proxies in EF and I want to apply a similar pattern to an application I am creating. So basically, I want to create a dynamic class at runtime that inherits from an existing class, in order to add some extra properties that will allow me to keep track of certain things in my application. I have read a bit about the DynamicObject and RealProxy, but it is not evident to me how they would help me achieve similar behaviour like EF-proxies have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a simple dynamic proxy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387004/how-to-make-a-simple-dynamic-proxy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Another option: Castle's DynamicProxy2.

Comment: @Amy : Thank you! I have checked Castle's Dynamic proxy. I managed to use the Dynamic object and extend a class with new properties. However, the result is still a dynamic object. How is EF managing to create a class named something like System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EntityName_LOG_GUID_FOLLOWS?

Comment: It creates a dynamic module that contains types.  (Note the distinction: the *module* is dynamic, which contains types you create at runtime, but those types aren't 'dynamic types').  Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467235/creating-dynamic-type-from-typebuilder-with-a-base-class-and-additional-fields-g).  I've fiddled with that before, it's quite painful to work with, but doable.  You can search the EF source code for "TypeBuilder", should return some hits.

Comment: Even if you don't follow the `TypeBuilder` approach, I consider it useful to learn.  IMO, it will help expand your knowledge of how C# works under the covers.  I proposed DynamicProxy2 simply because its easier and more useful, particularly if you use Dependency Injection.  IIRC (and i could be wrong on this) DynamicProxy2 uses `TypeBuilder` internally.

Comment: @Amy Thank you! This helped a bit to narrow my search for a solution.