# Create a new type based on other type, just changing the name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a type and want to create a new type, based on this type and just want to change the name.

Example:

```
var oldType = someObject.GetType();

var type = CreateNewType(oldType, "newType");
```

Please let me explain myself:

I'm creating several databases dynamically (by adding the model on an EF Core context). This works great but only on the first try but not on the second one because he keeps the previous tables as singleton contexts (attached to the type for what I have seen).

Comment: Seriously....why? And what does "based on" mean?: Derived from? A carbon copy of with a different name? What?

Comment: I have an EF Core Context that is dynamic. The DI apparently has a singleton database creation, which only works on the first try. If you create a new database migration with dynamic behaviour he will try to add the tables previously added.

Comment: I don't feel like there is enough information here. I would suggest investigating either not using Singletons in DI (so you can spin up different DB contexts), or using different schemas (iirc, the default is [dbo.], but you can change that).

Comment: They are different contexts in theory. The model is different, but they are added on runtime upon the same class. That's the problem. Simply a new type would do the trick (hacky as hell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just here to answer the question itself, even though is not the best solution:

Can be adapted from here:

[Creating dynamic type from TypeBuilder with a base class and additional fields generates an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467235/creating-dynamic-type-from-typebuilder-with-a-base-class-and-additional-fields-g)

Code:

```
public class ClassBuilder
{
    readonly AssemblyName _assemblyName;

    public ClassBuilder(string className)
    {
        _assemblyName = new AssemblyName(className);
    }

    public Type CopyType(Type type, string name)
    {
        var assemblyBuilder =
            AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(name), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");

        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(_assemblyName.FullName
            , TypeAttributes.Public |
              TypeAttributes.Class |
              TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
              TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
              TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
              TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
            , type);

        typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                                             MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to build a new type at run-time is to use some heavy-duty reflection to create IL code on the fly:

- [Is there a way to build a new type during Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929349/is-there-a-way-to-build-a-new-type-during-runtime)

That having been said, unless you have *very specific need* for that, this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661). I suggest that you create a new question describing the specific problem you are facing with EF core (including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and let the EF specialists suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, it is an XY problem. But regardless of that, I already have that code in here. I just need to find a way to create a type that extends from the one that has the logic. This does the trick but is still for sure hacky. Eventually, will have thousands of new types, and I don't know if that is a problem in the long run